# Exynos 5 DVFS or turning off cores in Ubuntu - Scaling frequency for one of the cores only (dual core) (cpufreq)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, power-management, arm

I was wondering if there is possible to scale only one of the cpu cores in the A15 in Exynos 5 ? I have tried using e.g cpufreq-set -c 1 -f 500MHz, but both cores are set to the same frequency. When running cpufreq-info, it displays that : "CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0 1" on both CPU 0 and CPU 1. Maybe this means that both cores are scaled.

However, is there any way of turning off a core, or to perform frequency scaling of individual cores in Ubuntu ?